# Number of matchings of a k-partite graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am not a mathematician, I need the answer to this problem to verify that I'm on the right track with a program that I'm writing.

Consider a graph of k partitions, each partition having n vertices.
Each vertex may be either unconnected, or connected to exactly one other vertex but that vertex must be in a different partition.

The question is then: how many different matchings (permutations) can one make?

For k=3 the answer is 4, 51, 1126, 37201, 1670136, 96502339, ... (for n = 1, 2, 3, etc). I need at least the answer for k=4 however (for a few values of n).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of the number of matchings of a tripartite graph can be found in the OEIS under [A293075](http://oeis.org/A293075) and gives a formula:

$$\sum_{i,j,k} \binom{n}{i}^2 \binom{n}{j}\binom{n-i}{j} \binom{n-i}{k}\binom{n-j}{k}i!\,j!\,k!$$

The reason this formula works is as follows: we pick values $i,j,k$ for the number of edges that go from part 1 to part 2, from part 1 to part 3,  and from part 2 to part 3. Then

- $\binom ni^2 i!$ chooses the edges of the first kind: $\binom ni$ ways to choose vertices in part 1, $\binom ni$ ways to choose vertices in part 2, and $i!$ ways to match them.
- $\binom nj \binom{n-i}j j!$ chooses the edges of the second kind: $\binom {n-i}{j}$ ways to choose vertices in part 1, $\binom nj$ ways to choose vertices in part 3, and $j!$ ways to match them.
- $\binom{n-i}k \binom{n-j}k k!$ chooses the edges of the third kind: $\binom{n-i}k$ ways to choose vertices in part 2, $\binom{n-j}{k}$ ways to choose vertices in part 3, and $k!$ ways to match them.

Next, we sum over all values of $i,j,k$. The presence of the binomial coefficients means that we don't have to worry about making sure these are in any particular range: we'll just get $0$ for all invalid terms.

So we can generalize this to $4$-partite matching pretty easily, although the formula looks intimidating:

$$\sum_{a,b,c,d,e,f} \binom na^2 \binom nb \binom{n-a}{b} \binom nc \binom{n-a-b}{c} \binom{n-a}{d} \binom{n-b}{d} \\ \binom{n-a-d}{e}\binom{n-c}{e} \binom{n-b-d}{f} \binom{n-c-e}{f} a!\,b!\,c!\,d!\,e!\,f!$$

The sequence I compute begins $1, 10, 513, 60058, 12328801, 3888782346, 1738720663345, \dots$.

Comment: Great!!! That means one of my programs is correct ;). Unfortunately, I need the other to be correct.. but at least now I have a way to verify it :).

Comment: Here is the program that I wrote that turns out to be working: https://ideone.com/XjF1Ci